# How can I view the full name of drop down items on iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

For a dropdown list on a website, iOS shows only the first few characters and then ellipses for items with a long name. Is it possible to somehow see the full text of each item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try selecting the item and then viewing the dropdown list in **view** mode, not **selection** mode. But As far as I know there is no way, in selection mode, to change how Apple presents the choices.

Comment: what do you mean by "view mode"? how do you get to it?

Comment: I mean when viewing the regular webpage. Perhaps the normal HTML view shows the full text, even if it isn't viewable in selection mode.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to turn your phone to a landscape mode...